# Git server: shortening clone path

Tags: git, server

I have set up a little git server that is accessed with ssh resulting in this clone statement:

`git clone -v git@server:/opt/git/resources.git`

Is there a way to get the same result without the `/opt/git` part?

i.e. `git clone -v git@server:/resources.git`

Comment: `/` -- root folder, apparently this is wrong. More or less working solution is `:resources.git`, however also wrong. Do your homework and you get why. Though, if it's separate user and standalone server specifically for Git (neither http(s), nor ssh), that would probably work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default base directory is the home directory of the server-side user (in your case, "git"). If you put the repository in `/home/git` (or wherever that user's home directory happens to be), then you can use

```
git clone git@server:resources.git
```

It's possible that this is not the case, depending on what git server you're using. You haven't specified, and you seem to be using full paths, so I am guessing this is a simple "remote ssh shell server" setup, not something specific such as Gitlab or gitolite. If you are using a specific git server software, you should mention it in your question.

In that case, you may also be able to add a symbolic link to accomplish this without having to move the repository's location on the server.

```
ln -s /opt/git/resources.git ~git/resources.git
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I added a symbolic link and now it works.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper Good point - I will put that in the answer, it may be useful for future readers too.